# View folder contents in Android using default explorer

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to programatically launch a default file explorer to show me the contents of a folder.

I'm using this code, but it crashes:

```
    Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera")); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setData(startDir);
    startActivity(intent);
```

LogCat shows "No Activity found to handle the Intent"...

What's my best option to do this? I want the user to see the contents of the folder and be able to click the files (e.g. click a video and launch it with default player, click a PDF and open it etc).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately there seem to be no standard way to do this, I was searching for the exact same thing before and couldn't find out any solution. There are 2 alternative methods that might work for you:

**1) Use a general intent and let the user pick his/her file manager**
This is safe and easy but a little far from what we really want

```
Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera"));
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(startDir);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Don't use `intent.setType("file/*");`, it's not a standard MIME type.

**2) Use Specific Intents that the famous file managers provide** The well known file managers have their own custom intent filters that accept a directory path which allows simple browsing. Some of them are here: [OI file manager](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/916), [ES Explorer](http://www.estrongs.com/en/support/developers.html)

Maybe you could check if the user have these specific file managers installed and then use this solution, else fallback to general intent.

For now these are the only two options you have. I will update this post if I find out any better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Can you please explain me what exactly does this instruction do:  `intent.setType("*/*");` -as far as I can see it is the only difference between your code and mine (besides the safer directory path) and I have never used this intent field before.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru It's to make sure every possible file manager installed on the device will show up in the "Complete action with..", the `"*/*"` is the most general MIME type so any file manager would be ok with that. Some people use `intent.setType("file/*");` but that's a non standard MIME and can cause the program to crash.

The only thing that is annoying is `setType("*/*")` will show other programs too, like camera, gallery and whatnot.

Comment: I can confirm that using `setType("file/*")` crashes my tablet with `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=file/* }`

Comment: is there any permissions needed for this?

Comment: This code also display option to select photos from google drive .But if a file select from google drive , it returns null path in onActivityResult . So to handle in that situation ?

Comment: According to the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building, "If you want to set both the URI and MIME type, do not call setData() and setType() because they each nullify the value of the other. Always use setDataAndType() to set both URI and MIME type." So the above code is only setting the type, not the data (`startDir`).

Answer (score 1):

Although I could not get the OI file manager to go to a specific directory, the following opens up the OI File Manager directly and goes to the last directory it was in.

```
Intent importFileIntent = new Intent();
importFileIntent.setType( "file/*" );

// Does nothing. 
// Uri startingDir = Uri.fromFile( new File(    
//      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera"));
// importFileIntent.setData( startingDirectory );

importFileIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );

// Ensure that there's an activity to handle the intent.
if (importFileIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) return;

startActivityForResult(importFileIntent, REQUEST_FILE_IMPORT);
```

If anybody has further success, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Your code is working fine.But it also showing google drive for select a file . When i choose a file from google drive , it returns null .  Is there any solution to hide google drive option or to get file path of google drive.